# Find the first column in the matrix, in which all elements are positive.

Tags: python, matrix

Find in the matrix the first column, in which all elements are positive. Signs of elements of the previous column change.

For example: In the matrix the column 2 has all positive elements.

```
matrix = [[-5, -6, 2], [7, 2, 1], [8, -4, 9]]
```

Then the previous column changes the signs.

```
matrix = [[-5, 6, 2], [7, -2, 1], [8, 4, 9]]
```

Comment: Please mention what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
matrix = [[-5, -6, 2], [7, 2, 1], [8, -4, 9]]

# column is positive until proven negativity.
results = [True, True, True]

# We loop over the rows...
for row in matrix:

    # And we loop over all the items in the row...
    for index,item in enumerate(row):

        # If the element is negative, item > 0 will be False, and this way results[index] will be set as False and will be True no more.
        results[index] = results[index] and (item > 0)

for index2,result in enumerate(results):
    if result:
        print "The {0} column is positive".format(index2)

        # Calculate the previous columns
        previous = index2 - 1

        # We invert the sign of the position 'previous' of every row.
        for row in matrix:
            row[previous] = - row[previous]

        break
```

After running the script, the results list should be like this

```
print results
[False, False, True]
```

This means that the last column is positive.

Comment: prints:  ***IndexError: list index out of range***

Comment: I have no tested it. I will tested it for improve the answer

Comment: But, how could change the signs of the previous column?

Comment: I updated my answer. I didn't see the second part of the algorithm

Answer (score 0):

I do not know python well so I write it in C++ code

```
int previous_col = 0;
int row_count = 0;

for (int col = 0; col < columns; ++col)
{
   for (int row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
   {
      if (matrix[row][col] >= 0)
         ++row_count;
   }
   if (row_count = rows)
   {
      col - 1 < 0 ? columns - 1 : col - 1;
      for (int row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
      {
         matrix[row][col] *= -1;
      }
      break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try Numpy

Do you have numpy available to you? It was made for these operations and allows you to write much more concise and vectorized code.

#### Import and convert lists to ndarray

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array(matrix)
```

#### Output

```
In [21]: A
Out[21]: 
array([[-5, -6,  2],
       [ 7,  2,  1],
       [ 8, -4,  9]])
```

#### Index of first all positive column

```
ix = np.argmax((A >= 0).all(axis=0))
```

#### Flip sign of previous column

Using modulus over the number of columns in case the first non negative column was 0

```
prev_ix = (ix - 1) % A.shape[1]
A[:, prev_ix] *= -1
```

#### Output

```
In [24]: A
Out[24]: 
array([[-5,  6,  2],
       [ 7, -2,  1],
       [ 8,  4,  9]])
```

#### Finally

You could actually stuff all those operations into a one liner, albeit a little less readable :)

```
A[:, ((np.argmax((A >= 0).all(axis=0)) - 1) % A.shape[1])] *= 1
```